# R: Condition based on observed result

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a R `data.frame` with fast Fourier Transform results. The columns are Power and Frequency. For purpose of my study, I have selected a portion of the full FFT results (frequencies between 1 and 48).

I have to identify `maximum 5 peaks (highest powers)` inside the frequency range. Also, there is a condition that we won't consider any peaks that are less than 45% of the highest peak. I will share the code below:

```
df_FFT_2 <- select(filter(df_FFT, frequency <49 & frequency >0 ),c(frequency, power))
with(df_FFT_2,plot(frequency,power, type = "l"))



max_power <- max(df_FFT_2$power)
max_freq <- df_FFT_2$frequency[which(df_FFT_2$power == max_power)]
print(c(max_power, max_freq))


# Calculate a threshold and then create a filtered data.frame
threshold <- 0.45 * max_power
df_filt <- df_FFT_2[which(df_FFT_2$power > threshold), ]
df_filt <- df_filt[order(-df_filt$power), ]
if(nrow(df_filt) > 5){
  df_filt <- df_filt[1:5, ]
}


freq_FFT <- df_filt$frequency 
n = length(freq_FFT)
```

This code works fine. With different input data-sets, I get 1(min),2,3,4 or 5(max) peaks.

However, this is a small part of the full prototype I am working with. I have found that when I get only one peak, the final results are not very good. I would like to select `at least 2 peaks,` even if the second peak `does not satisfy` the threshold condition.

I would like to put a condition

```
if (length(freq_FFT) < 2){
   disregard the threshold condition and find the two highest peaks.
}
```

I haven't been able to modify the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider sorting the main data beforehand and then add a conditional block that stacks (using `rbind`) the filtered data with top two in main dataset. And because the single one row may be the leading *power*, run a `unique` to de-dupe the data. Code comments in below signify adjustments:

```
...
threshold <- 0.45 * max_power
df_FFT_2 <- df_FFT_2[order(-df_FFT_2$power), ]                  # ORDER BY DESCENDING POWER
df_filt <- df_FFT_2[which(df_FFT_2$power > threshold), ]
df_filt <- df_filt[order(-df_filt$power), ]

if(nrow(df_filt) > 5) {
  df_filt <- head(df_filt, 5)                                   # CHANGED TO head()
}

# NEW IF LOGIC BLOCK
if(nrow(df_filt) < 2) {
  df_filt <- rbind(df_filt,
                   head(df_FFT_2, 2))                           # TOP TWO  ROWS
  df_filt <- unique(df_filt)
}
```